# How to connect the angular to MongoDB

Tags: angular, mongodb

I was not able to find a way to connect my database to my user interface which I make in angular. So anyone can suggest to me how to overcome my problem by the simpler way???
needed a simpler code to rectify the error

Comment: did you try this? https://medium.com/@BaaniLeen/connecting-angular-5-app-to-mongodb-database-mean-stack-9b4b4232e219

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly communicate to any database via angular.
You need to create middleware(server) using nodejs, python or any other.

Answer (score 2):

[the-modern-application-stack-part-4-building-a-client-ui-using-angular-2-formerly-angularjs-and-typescript](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/the-modern-application-stack-part-4-building-a-client-ui-using-angular-2-formerly-angularjs-and-typescript)

> Use MongoDB Stitch

[MongoDB Stitch](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-stitch-the-latest-and-best-way-to-build-your-app)

import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

import { StitchClientFactory } from "mongodb-stitch";

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect the front-end directly to a database. You need a back-end for that.
Check out [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) if you're looking for something in JavaScript.
There are a lot of courses for MEAN stack on Udemy. You could learn from those.